# Java loop through arraylist and remove any objects of type item with a matching code

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to do a task of looping through an arraylist of objects of type item. Each item object has a code variable. If there is already an object with the code then it is removed from the list.

Code:

```
//Search list for item based on code. 
//If item with code is found, it is removed/deleted from the list. 
//Else user is told "No item Found"

public void deleteItem(String code)
{
    boolean found = false;

    for(Item item : items)
    {
        if(item.getCode().equals(code))
        {
            found = true;
            items.remove(item);
        }
    }

    if(found)
    {
        System.out.println("Found and removed item with code: " + code);          
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.println("No item with code" + code + "found");
    }
}
```

I get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Any help please?

Comment: second link in google by `ConcurentModificationException` https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception

Comment: An alternative way: `boolean found = items.removeIf(item -> code.equals(item.getCode()));`